# How to update Navigation Link subscript with an array of views inside a ForEach Loop?

Tags: swiftui

I am utilizing a search bar from a Kavsoft Tutorial here: "https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=nuag1PILxCA&t=14s", I'm wondering on how to add navigation links to each of the items, I decided on embedding the itemView inside a navigation link with an array of views to loop through but it seems that it doesn't accept the index as a parameter giving "Cannot convert value of type 'item' to expected argument type 'Int'", instead I incremented the subscript on appear in the navigation link, although that updates the variable, but it doesn't seem to work for the different views themselves only navigating to the first view.

I've linked all the code needed to reproduce the problem but due to my incredibly limited experience in reproducing the problem in as less code as possible, I am not able to do so. Below the main issue of concern is the block starting from the VStack. Starting the program can be done by just adding Search_Bar() to content view body.

```
struct Home: View {
    
    let views : [AnyView] = [ AnyView(untitled_Skull()), AnyView(dogs()), AnyView(cats()) ]

    @Binding var filteredItems : [item]
    
    var body: some View {
        ScrollView(.vertical, showsIndicators: false) {
            
            var i = 0
            
            VStack(spacing: 15){
                ForEach(filteredItems){index in
                    NavigationLink(destination: views[i]
                    ) {
                        itemView(item: index)
                    }.onAppear() {
                        i = i + 1
                    }
                }
            }
            .padding()
        }
    }
}

func add(value: Int) -> Int {
    let value = value + 1
    return value
}
struct itemView: View {
    
    var item: item
    @State var show = false
    
    var body: some View {
        
        HStack(spacing: 15){
            
            VStack {
                let colorArray: [Color] = [.yellowLichtenstien, .redHaring, .orangeBasquiat, .pinkWarhol]
                HStack {
                    Text(item.name)
                        .foregroundColor(.white)
                        .bold()
                        .padding(.leading)
                    Spacer()
            }
                HStack {
                    Text(item.subText)
                        .bold()
                        .foregroundColor (.white)
                        .font(.subheadline)
                        .padding(.leading)
                    
                    Circle()
                        .frame(width: 5, height: 5)
                        .foregroundColor(colorArray[item.color])
                    
                    Text(item.subText2)
                        .bold()
                        .foregroundColor (.white)
                        .font(.subheadline)
                    Spacer()
                }
                Spacer()
            }
        }
        .padding(.horizontal)
    }
}
```

```
struct item: Identifiable {
    
    var id = UUID().uuidString
    // both Image And Name Are Same....
    var name: String
    // since all Are Apple Native Apps...
    var color: Int
    
    var subText: String
    
    var subText2: String
}

var searchItems = [

    item(name: "Untitled (Skull)", color: 0, subText: "1983", subText2: "yay"),
    item(name: "Dogs", color: 1, subText: "1972", subText2: "wow"),
    item(name: "Cats", color: 2, subText: "1968", subText2: "oof")
]
```

```
struct Search_Bar: View {
    @State var filteredItems = searchItems
    
    var body: some View {

        CustomNavigationView(view: AnyView(Home(filteredItems: $filteredItems)), placeHolder: "Museums, Art or anything else.", largeTitle: true, title: "Search",
                             
            onSearch: { (txt) in
                if txt != ""{
                    self.filteredItems = searchItems.filter{$0.name.lowercased().contains(txt.lowercased())}
                }
                else{
                    self.filteredItems = searchItems
                }
        }, onCancel: {
            // Do Your Own Code When Search And Canceled....
            self.filteredItems = searchItems
            
        })
        .ignoresSafeArea()
    }
}

struct Search_Bar_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        Search_Bar()
    }
}
```

```
import SwiftUI

struct CustomNavigationView: UIViewControllerRepresentable {
    
    
    func makeCoordinator() -> Coordinator {
        return CustomNavigationView.Coordinator(parent: self)
    }
    
    // Just Change Your View That Requires Search Bar...
    var view: AnyView
    
    // Ease Of Use.....
    
    var largeTitle: Bool
    var title: String
    var placeHolder: String
    
    // onSearch And OnCancel Closures....
    var onSearch: (String)->()
    var onCancel: ()->()
    
    // requre closure on Call...
    
    init(view: AnyView,placeHolder: String? = "Search",largeTitle: Bool? = true,title: String,onSearch: @escaping (String)->(),onCancel: @escaping ()->()) {
      
        self.title = title
        self.largeTitle = largeTitle!
        self.placeHolder = placeHolder!
        self.view = view
        self.onSearch = onSearch
        self.onCancel = onCancel
    }
    
    // Integrating UIKit Navigation Controller With SwiftUI View...
    func makeUIViewController(context: Context) -> UINavigationController {
        
        // requires SwiftUI View...
        let childView = UIHostingController(rootView: view)
        
        let controller = UINavigationController(rootViewController: childView)
        
        // Nav Bar Data...
        
        controller.navigationBar.topItem?.title = title
        controller.navigationBar.prefersLargeTitles = largeTitle
        
        // search Bar....
        
        let searchController = UISearchController()
        searchController.searchBar.placeholder = placeHolder
        
        // setting delegate...
        searchController.searchBar.delegate = context.coordinator
        
        // setting Search Bar In NavBar...
        // disabling hide on scroll...
        
        // disabling dim bg..
        searchController.obscuresBackgroundDuringPresentation = false
        
        controller.navigationBar.topItem?.hidesSearchBarWhenScrolling = false
        controller.navigationBar.topItem?.searchController = searchController
        
        return controller
    }
    
    func updateUIViewController(_ uiViewController: UINavigationController, context: Context) {
        
        // Updating Real Time...
        uiViewController.navigationBar.topItem?.title = title
        uiViewController.navigationBar.topItem?.searchController?.searchBar.placeholder = placeHolder
        uiViewController.navigationBar.prefersLargeTitles = largeTitle
    }
    
    // search Bar Delegate...
    
    class Coordinator: NSObject,UISearchBarDelegate{
        
        var parent: CustomNavigationView
        
        init(parent: CustomNavigationView) {
            self.parent = parent
        }
        
        func searchBar(_ searchBar: UISearchBar, textDidChange searchText: String) {
            // when text changes....
            self.parent.onSearch(searchText)
        }
        
        func searchBarCancelButtonClicked(_ searchBar: UISearchBar) {
            // when cancel button is clicked...
            self.parent.onCancel()
        }
    }
}
```

Letting the random view below for the array being for example:

```
import SwiftUI

struct cats: View {
    var body: some View {
        Text("cats") //replacing this with dogs or untitled skull as an example.
    }
}

struct cats_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        cats()
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `ForEach` getting the item and its index in the closure :

```
ForEach(Array(filteredItems.enumerated()), id: \.1.id) { index, item in
                NavigationLink(destination: views[index]){
                    Text(item.name)
                }
            }
```

For example :

```
struct ListItem: Identifiable {
    let id = UUID()
    let name: String
}

struct SwiftUIView17: View {
    @State private var filteredItems = ["John", "Bob", "Maria"].map(ListItem.init)
    
    let views = [AnyView(Text("John destination")), AnyView(Text("Bob destination")), AnyView(Text("Maria destination"))]
    
    var body: some View {
        ScrollView {
            ForEach(Array(filteredItems.enumerated()), id: \.1.id) { index, item in
                NavigationLink(destination: views[index]){
                    Text(item.name)
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

But it would be better not to use `AnyView` but a `ViewBuilder` :

```
struct SwiftUIView17: View {
    @State private var filteredItems = ["John", "Bob", "Maria"].map(ListItem.init)
    
    @ViewBuilder func destination(for itemIndex: Int) -> some View {
        switch itemIndex {
        case 0: Text("John destination")
        case 1: Text("Bob destination").foregroundColor(.red)
        case 2: Rectangle()
        default: Text("error")
        }
    }
    
    var body: some View {
        ScrollView {
            ForEach(Array(filteredItems.enumerated()), id: \.1.id) { index, item in
                NavigationLink(destination: destination(for: index)){
                    Text(item.name)
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: They both seem to work, but the issue for me that still remains is that because the index position changes depending on the number of filtered items remaining, the first filtered item will always navigate towards page John even when I search and press on "Bob". Is there a way to fix the position?

Comment: Never mind I found that the best way to solve that issue was to manually force an ID as an Integer and just navigating to that index if the filteredItems.count != 0.